# Which system files are updated when you install/update/remove a package?

Tags: installation, updates, files, purge

When a new package is installed (even from source), or existing ones are updated/deleted/purged, some system files seem to be updated. Which are these?

I want the files which contain the list of these packages and their status, not the packages themselves.

**EDIT:** A few of the files I came to know are `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` which get updated when you install a new package. I just want an exhaustive list of all these files.

Comment: To know of all the files a process handles, one can use [strace](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58887/how-do-i-monitor-opened-files-of-a-process-in-realtime) — in your case, you would do strace against the dpkg command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `dpkg`

`dpkg` keeps some information in `/var/lib/dpkg/`:

- `info/PACKAGENAME.*` (where `PACKAGENAME` is the name of the package): file list and  control files from the `DEBIAN/` folder inside the package
- `diversions`: diverted file locations, see [dpkg-divert](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html)
- `alternatives`: information for the Debian alternatives system, see [update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)
- `triggers`: package triggers, see [dpkg-trigger](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg-trigger.1.html)

### apt

- `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`: package information not used by `dpkg`, like the *auto-installed* flags
- `/var/log/apt/`: several log files

Comment: Thanks a lot, @FlorinDiesch! Are you sure no other system files are generally affected by the above mentioned processes?

Comment: It's what I know it's modified by `dpkg` and `apt` but I didn't check the source code to see if there's anything else.